# How to change resolution on ubuntu windows app

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I got the ubuntu app from windows store and connected to it via remote desktop, but everything's super tiny and there's just one resolution in the Display settings. I found some xrandr commands to add other resolutions:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1000_60.00"  139.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1000 1003 1013 1038 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1680x1000_60.00"
```

and it did add another resolution to the menu but selecting it doesn't change anything.

[image]